# I saw/have seen him while I was there

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, past-simple

Let’s say that while on a vacation I run across someone I knew. By now, the vacation has already ended.
Which of the following sentences is correct?

1. I saw him while I was there.
2. I’ve seen him while I was there.

I think only the first one is correct, because ‘while I was there’ is a finished time expression, but I would like to make sure.
Thank you!

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.